# How to transform a Polars DataFrame to a pySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, pyspark, python-polars

How to correctly transform a Polars DataFrame to a pySpark DataFrame?

More specifically, the conversion methods which I've tried all seem to have problems parsing columns containing arrays / lists.

create spark dataframe

```
data = [{"id": 1, "strings": ['A', 'C'], "floats": [0.12, 0.43]},
        {"id": 2, "strings": ['B', 'B'], "floats": [0.01]},
        {"id": 3, "strings": ['C'], "floats": [0.09, 0.01]}
        ]

sparkdf = spark.createDataFrame(data)
```

convert it to polars

```
import pyarrow as pa
import polars as pl
pldf = pl.from_arrow(pa.Table.from_batches(sparkdf._collect_as_arrow()))
```

try to convert back to spark dataframe (attempt 1)

```
spark.createDataFrame(pldf.to_pandas())


TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
TypeError: Unable to infer the type of the field floats.
```

try to convert back to spark dataframe (attempt 2)

```
schema = sparkdf.schema
spark.createDataFrame(pldf.to_pandas(), schema)

TypeError: field floats: ArrayType(DoubleType(), True) can not accept object array([0.12, 0.43]) in type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

relevant: [How to transform Spark dataframe to Polars dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73203318/how-to-transform-spark-dataframe-to-polars-dataframe)

Comment: I had a similar problem. I ended up saving the dataframe as Parquet, and then loading it back with Spark.

@Dean MacGregor answer works well for smaller datasets, but for big datasets converting to dicts takes a long time.

I am hoping Spark allows to create a dataframe from an Arrow table

Comment: Unfortunately the reason I want to convert it to Spark in the first place is so that I can save it :).  I'm in Azure Databricks and need to save to Azure Storage gen2.  Spark handles this perfectly, but Polars does not.

Comment: I also use Azure Databricks and I am able to save the files with Polars. However there is a difference in the path: 

with Polars
`df.collect().write_parquet(f'/dbfs/mnt/..)`

with Spark I start with /mnt and skip the /dbfs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
spark.createDataFrame(pldf.to_dicts())
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
spark.createDataFrame({x:y.to_list() for x,y in pldf.to_dict().items()})
```

Since the `to_dict` method returns polars Series instead of lists, I'm using a comprehension to convert the Series into regular lists which spark comprehends.

Comment: i get:
```raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the right way to do this while reading 'In-Memory Analytics with Apache Arrow' by Matthew Topol.

You can do:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_polars.to_pandas())
```

It's quite fast.

I also tried converting to an Arrow-backed Pandas dataframe first (i.e. `df_polars.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True)`) but it does not work: Spark complains that it does not know how to handle column types such as large strings (the UTF8 in Polars) or unsigned integers.

Not setting `spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled` to true increased the time 90-fold in my test (from 1.5 seconds to 2 minutes 18 seconds).

Comment: Note that it requires Pandas 1.5.x or higher

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame.transform(func: Callable [ […], DataFrame], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) → pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame [source] ¶ Returns a new DataFrame. Concise syntax for chaining custom transformations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).