# Polars Dataframe to Spark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, python-polars

I have a very big polars dataframe (3M rows X 145 cols of different dtypes) as a result of a huge polars concatenation.

I'm looking for the most efficient and fast way to convert it to a PySpark SQL Dataframe (`pyspark.sql.DataFrame`).

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74719898/how-to-transform-a-polars-dataframe-to-a-pyspark-dataframe) I tried to:

- convert it to Pandas using `use_pyarrow_extension_array=True`  --> discarded because the result Pandas dataframe has unsupported types in Spark's schema validation (i.e. Spark's `TimestampNTZType` and `DateType` accepts only Python's `datetime` objects, nullable types becomes `NAType` instead of `np.nan`).
- convert it to Pandas using `use_pyarrow_extension_array=False` --> looks good, but it goes OOM on such big DataFrame
- convert it to dicts  --> discarded because it goes OOM

Another weird thing I noted is that the following code produce the same spark dataframe, maybe the issue is that Spark's verifySchema does not work with pandas' arrow backed dataframes.

```py
pandas_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()  # assume this is my big DataFrame
polars_dataframe = pl.from_pandas(pandas_dataframe)

pandas_2_spark = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_dataframe, schema=my_spark_schema, verifySchema=True)
polars_2_spark = spark.createDataFrame(polars_dataframe.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True), schema=my_spark_schema, verifySchema=False)  # with verifySchema=True this would fail

pyspark.testing.utils.assertDataFrameEqual(polars_2_spark, pandas_2_spark)  # OK
```

Comment: Can you write it disk and read it back in using PySpark?

Comment: @Hericks that's an interesting suggestion. Would it be possible also to test the schema against an existing one as if I were creating the spark dataframe with `spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema, verifySchema=True)` ?

Answer (score 2):

When converting to a pandas DataFrame as an intermediate step takes too much memory, another approach would be to write the DataFrame to disk and read it back in using PySpark.

For more information on the writing process, consider the documentation of [`pl.DataFrame.write_parquet`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_parquet.html) (for `pl.DataFrame`s) and [`pl.LazyFrame.sink_parquet`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet.html) (for `pl.LazyFrame`s).

Subsequently, reading in the parquet file using PySpark and verifying a custom  schema can be done as follows:

```py
import spark

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType


CustomSchema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
])

df = spark.read.format("parquet").schema(CustomSchema).load(filepath)
```

We refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387021/spark-read-parquet-with-custom-schema) for more information on the schema validation.

Comment: If I write the Polars DataFrame to disk and I try to read it back as you suggested I get some typing error like: `SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException: column: [timestamp], physicalType: INT64, logicalType: timestamp_ntz`. Looks like Spark is not able to create a DataFrame from an arrow backed one

Comment: @Usernameless It sounds like your dataframe has a column of a type not supported by pandas. This is in line with what you described when using pandas. Is it an option for you to convert the dtype in polars before writing to disk?

Comment: I think the problem is somehow related with the verifySchema in spark. I updated my original question adding more details on the tests I did with pandas, polars and spark

Comment: @Usernameless The different results for the schema validation indeed seem weird. Possibly, you can open a bug report on the spark GitHub page.