# IndexOutOfBoundsException when converting Pyspark DataFrame to Polars DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, python-polars

I'm using the following code from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73205690/6297800)

```py
import polars as pl
arrow = spark_df._collect_as_arrow()
pl.from_arrow(pa.Table.from_batches(arrow))
```

This works on a toy DataFrame with a handful of rows, but when I run it on a larger DataFrame with ~20 columns and ~10k rows I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 176.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 176.0 (TID 9148) (10.94.121.19 executor 6): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 16384, length: 4 (expected: range(0, 16384))
```

Any ideas? There are some ArrayType columns with nested StructTypes, is it possible that's causing some kind of issue?
Alternatively, is there another way to translate a Pyspark DataFrame to Polars without going through Pandas?

Here's the whole error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1365.getResult.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:428)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer.getResult(SocketAuthServer.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer.getResult(SocketAuthServer.scala:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 176.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 176.0 (TID 9148) (10.94.121.19 executor 6): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 16384, length: 4 (expected: range(0, 16384))
    at org.apache.arrow.memory.ArrowBuf.checkIndexD(ArrowBuf.java:318)
    at org.apache.arrow.memory.ArrowBuf.chk(ArrowBuf.java:305)
    at org.apache.arrow.memory.ArrowBuf.getInt(ArrowBuf.java:424)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.BaseRepeatedValueVector.getBufferSizeFor(BaseRepeatedValueVector.java:229)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.ListVector.getBufferSizeFor(ListVector.java:621)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowFieldWriter.getSizeInBytes(ArrowWriter.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowWriter.sizeInBytes(ArrowWriter.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.$anonfun$next$1(ArrowConverters.scala:228)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:203)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:366)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:364)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:345)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:339)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$7(Dataset.scala:3889)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$3(SparkContext.scala:2751)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:832)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:835)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:690)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3093)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3040)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3034)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:3034)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3302)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3243)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3231)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2657)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2640)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2752)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$6(Dataset.scala:3887)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$3(Dataset.scala:3891)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$3$adapted(Dataset.scala:3857)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3951)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3949)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$2(Dataset.scala:3857)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$2$adapted(Dataset.scala:3856)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer$.$anonfun$serveToStream$2(SocketAuthServer.scala:153)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer$.$anonfun$serveToStream$1(SocketAuthServer.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer$.$anonfun$serveToStream$1$adapted(SocketAuthServer.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketFuncServer.handleConnection(SocketAuthServer.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketFuncServer.handleConnection(SocketAuthServer.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$4(SocketAuthServer.scala:70)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer$$anon$1.run(SocketAuthServer.scala:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 16384, length: 4 (expected: range(0, 16384))
    at org.apache.arrow.memory.ArrowBuf.checkIndexD(ArrowBuf.java:318)
    at org.apache.arrow.memory.ArrowBuf.chk(ArrowBuf.java:305)
    at org.apache.arrow.memory.ArrowBuf.getInt(ArrowBuf.java:424)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.BaseRepeatedValueVector.getBufferSizeFor(BaseRepeatedValueVector.java:229)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.complex.ListVector.getBufferSizeFor(ListVector.java:621)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowFieldWriter.getSizeInBytes(ArrowWriter.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowWriter.sizeInBytes(ArrowWriter.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.$anonfun$next$1(ArrowConverters.scala:228)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:203)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:366)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:364)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:345)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:339)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$7(Dataset.scala:3889)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$3(SparkContext.scala:2751)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:832)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:835)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:690)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/utils.py", line 54, in op_execution_error_boundary
    yield
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dagster/_utils/__init__.py", line 445, in iterate_with_context
    next_output = next(iterator)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/compute_generator.py", line 124, in _coerce_op_compute_fn_to_iterator
    result = invoke_compute_fn(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/compute_generator.py", line 118, in invoke_compute_fn
    return fn(context, **args_to_pass) if context_arg_provided else fn(**args_to_pass)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/etxlib/etxdagster/pipelines/retrieve_phewas/pipeline.py", line 262, in retrieve_phewas_op
    s3_paths, output_metadata = handle_output(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/etxlib/etxdagster/pipelines/retrieve_phewas/output.py", line 213, in handle_output
    write_results(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/etxlib/etxdagster/pipelines/retrieve_phewas/output.py", line 89, in write_results
    pdf = polars_from_spark(subset)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/etxlib/core/common/utils.py", line 26, in polars_from_spark
    return pl.from_arrow(pa.Table.from_batches(spark_df._collect_as_arrow()))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py", line 296, in _collect_as_arrow
    jsocket_auth_server.getResult()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
```

Comment: You're already not going through pandas. You're going through arrow which should be copyless. As to your guess about nested structs, try to make a smaller df that is of the form spark_df.sql("select not_struct_cols from table"). As you can tell I don't really know spark syntax but I think you get the idea. Alternatively save your spark_df to a parquet file and then just open that file with polars to see what happens.