# Polars read_parquet runs forever in airflow

Tags: airflow, python-polars

I try to read parquet file with polar in Airflow DAG, but function runs forever with no exceptions or errors in airflow logs.

When I change polars to pandas, everything works fine.
I use simple version of Airflow with sqlite database and SequentialExecutor.
I tried running task via python and everything also works.
What can be a problem?

Comment: Hi , Can you please paste the error you are getting, it is hard to tell without seeing any error logs?

Comment: Which version of Polars?

Comment: 0.17.15 version

Answer (score 0):

Also, spark is disturbed, polar is not distributed. When you use polar that is single machine , however spark allows you to read big data files such as parquet on single machine (to a limit depends upon the size) or on multi machine architecture. Give a look at this threat -> [How to transform Spark dataframe to Polars dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73203318/how-to-transform-spark-dataframe-to-polars-dataframe)

If you are using the local machine , then just do this command
`df = pl.read_parquet("/my/path/*")` otherwise if you are reading from cloud then you might need to use the pyarrow to read multiple files at once without iterating over them

Comment: Hi, thank you!
I am using local machine and pl.read_parquet(my_path, use_pyarrow = True) solved this problem, but over function in polars still doesnt work (like select).
I see no errors, just task never stops.

Comment: Can you try this `def select_polar_df(df: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
  return df.select([
    pl.col('colA'),
    pl.col('colA') 
  ])

Comment: This function also runs forever.